# Highlighting of selected item of ListView if background color of stack layout is set

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, highlight

I was trying to check if selected item of listview (made of viewcell) is being highlighted when it is tapped or selected. I noticed if stacklayout is used in the viewcell and if the background color of that stacklayout is set, then highlight is not functioning. When, I removed the backgroundcolor property, Highlight becomes functional.

Is there a way to bypass that limitation?

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5"> 
        <ListView x:Name="List" SelectionMode="Single"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStored}" RowHeight="100" SeparatorColor="#2EC022"
                  SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell  >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Padding="5" ***BackgroundColor="LightGray">***

                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}"  HorizontalOptions="Start" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" BackgroundColor="LightGray" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Definition}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" MaxLines="10" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                            <!--<Label Text="Examples:" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Example1}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    MaxLines="10" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Example2}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    MaxLines="10" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>-->
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" Padding="5" >
            <Button Text="GetFullList" Command="{Binding GetList}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button Text="Delete" VerticalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding DeleteEntry }"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Grid or Frame that wrap a view with a border(Stacklayout) to do this.

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="5" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="Medium"
                                    Text="{Binding FullName}"
                                    TextColor="Orange" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame Padding="5" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="Medium"
                                    Text="{Binding FullName}"
                                    TextColor="Orange" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use frame and put your StackLayout in it, and set frame's BackgroundColor = transparent and Padding=0.